# Error : loadNamespace(x) there is no package called ‘devtools’

Tags: r, github, devtools, qiime

I was trying to install Github library using devtools.

```
if (!requireNamespace("devtools", quietly = TRUE)){install.packages("devtools")}
devtools::install_github("jbisanz/qiime2R")
```

Therefore, I installed devtools with the code below, and when I tried to use the installed devtools, the following error code occurred.

```
loadNamespace(x) there is no package called ‘devtools’
```

When devtools was installed with the code below, the following was output, and if anyone can give advice, I would appreciate it.

```
install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE)
```

```
-------------------------- [ERROR MESSAGE] ---------------------------
<stdin>:1:10: fatal error: ft2build.h: no such file or directory
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘ragg’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/ragg’
ERROR: dependency ‘httpuv’ is not available for package ‘shiny’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/shiny’
ERROR: dependency ‘ragg’ is not available for package ‘pkgdown’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/pkgdown’
ERROR: dependency ‘shiny’ is not available for package ‘miniUI’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/miniUI’
ERROR: dependencies ‘miniUI’, ‘pkgdown’ are not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/devtools’
```

Comment: Do you have rtools installed?

Comment: it looks like ragg failed to install, you could look into that more specifically. maybe they have an installation guide?

Comment: btw, you don't need {devtools} to install from GitHub, just use {remotes}, that may be easier to install

Comment: @MichaelChirico OMG, When I enter the command you mentioned, it works right away. It looks like you need to see it. Thank you very much.